# split with regex in java resulting an empty element

Tags: java

I am trying to split a String array and use delimiters to remove any whitespace (including `\t`) but I am getting an empty element `""` for some reason.

My Code:

```
String temp = "    x = x + 9";
String[] tempArr = temp.split("\\s+");
```

The result I am getting:

```
tempArr[0] = ""
tempArr[1] = "x"
tempArr[2] = "="
...
```

I do not understand why I am getting an empty element in the first index of the array.

Comment: This: `"\s+"` is a typo, right? It should be: `"\\s+"`.

Comment: Use `.trim()` before `.split(..)` to get rid of leading and trailing white spaces.

Comment: "I do not understand why I am getting an empty element in the first index of the array." what would you expect to get as result of `"AxB".split("x")`? And what in case of `"xAxB".split("x")`? Now simply change `x` with space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove empty results after splitting with regex in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451331/how-to-remove-empty-results-after-splitting-with-regex-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `split("\s+")` to `split("\\s+")` and use `trim()` earlier to get rid of all leading and trailing extra spaces

```
String[] tempArr = temp.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: My bad, I only focused on changing `\s` to `\\s` (which is unnecessary IMO and can't solve OP real problem because he must be using `\\s` to get *any* result, so there is no `\s` in his code) and missed fact that you *also* suggested using `trim()` method which was proper solution here. Sorry for downvote, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `"\\s+"` are a delimiter and in your given string `"    x = x + 9"` there are spaces in front of the string, that means the first set of spaces is separating empty word and x.

I will try to give you some example not using spaces:

```
String temp = ",a,b,c";
String[] tempArr = temp.split(",");
```

Will result as:

```
tempArr[0] = ""
tempArr[1] = "a"
tempArr[2] = "b"
tempArr[2] = "c"
```

Do you see why? Because in front of the first `","` there is empty string. It's same with spaces.

If you don't want to have first element empty, use function `.trim()` as @PRC_noob and @Pshemo already suggested. It will remove spaces from the beginning and the end of your string.